# Set unique key by combining two colums of a table using visual studio

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a unique key by combining two columns of a table using Visual Studio for Asp.net website. I know the way with the help of MySql command prompt, but I do not know graphically in visual studio.

Please help me..